# Merge 2 random images from different directories

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background, batch-processing

I have 2 folders which contain different number of image files, I want photoshop to combine them randomly using batch.

The first folder is `Backgrounds` which holds all the backgrounds, and the second folder is `Data` which holds all the images, I want photoshop to run over all the images inside `Data` and paste them over a random background image from `Backgrounds` folder.

The `Backgrounds` folder holds only 20 images of background and the `Data` folder holds over 2000 images.

How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you'll need a script for that: In Photoshop it's going to be quite simple one but you need to know the basics of scripting for PS. I believe it's also possible to do with `imagemagick`

Comment: Maybe you could use data sets and randomize the rows or cells in a spreadsheet application? Of course if you need to run it multiple times and needs to be randomized on every run, it could be too much work... or not?

Comment: I knew randomizing excel rows was going to be easy but I wasn't so sure about just randomizing the rows of a single column. It turns out that is also pretty simple. You can [follow this guide](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3151-excel-shuffle-rows-cells.html) up to step 3 and instead select the column you want to randomize + the rand() column then choose `Custom sort` from the list. In the window choose to sort by the `rand()` column.

Comment: the question is simple: what have you try? post some code please, we could help you better than now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found easier solution in node.js using `pic-generator`:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas')
const { forEach } = require('lodash');
const imagesDir = './pics/images/';
const bgDir = './pics/backgrounds/';

const width = 500
const height = 500

let bgs = [];
let images = [];

fs.readdir(imagesDir, (err, files) => {
    images = files;
    fs.readdir(bgDir, (err, files2) => {
        bgs = files2;


        let bgCount = 0;

        forEach(images, (img) => {
            const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.fillStyle = '#fff'
            context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            const imageToEdit = `${imagesDir}${img}`
            const bgIdx = bgCount % bgs.length;
            bgCount++;
            const bgImg = `${bgDir}${bgs[bgIdx]}`

            loadImage(imageToEdit).then(image => {
                loadImage(bgImg).then(bg => {
                    context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, 500, 500)
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 500, 500)

                    const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png')
                    fs.writeFileSync(imageToEdit, buffer)
                });

            })
        })

    });
});
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

#### I tried to make your idea:

It is not fluid and you will have to improve it a little *(and change all directories)* but this is the idea I think:

```bsh
echo OFF
CLS

: creating 2 directory where I will put the images mixed

md C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\union >nul 2>&1 
md C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\union\result >nul 2>&1 

    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    cd C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\back

    : now create a loop to control files and save them in a vector
    set n=1
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )

    : randomic function to decide what file it will take
    set /a dir=(%random%*13)/32768+1
    
    : put the file in the new directory 
    copy "!file[%dir%]!" C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\union

    : coping name and path (brutally)
    set srcback=!file[%dir%]!
    set backpath=C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\back\%srcback%
    
    
    : NOW, going to the other folder, same passages  
    cd C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\datah
    
    set n=1
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
   
    : modify the 8 with the number of your img
    set /a num=(%random%*8)/32768+1
    copy "!file[%num%]!" C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\union
    
    set srcdata=!file[%num%]!
    set datapath=C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\datah\%srcdata%
    
: -Then the unions of the images with imageMagick- 
: (In my opinion, it is the most useful kit for doing this type of automatic operation) 

magick convert %backpath% %datapath% -gravity Center -geometry 256x256+30+5 -composite -resize 512x512 
C:\Users\alessandro.golin\Desktop\union\result\%srcdata%%srcback%.png

: if you give to your program a cute name and you want to display it like if it is a chat,
: add %~n0: (it is not the real use of %~n0: but a sort of :|)
echo %~n0: bye :)
pause>nul
```

For uses of imageMagick see the [composite command](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#:%7E:text=The%20traditional%20method%20of%20combining,image%20at%20a%20time...) paragraph
Hope you like it `:)`

<sub>P.S: Someone know how to add the batch language identifier?</sub>